# How to Using JSON with visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, json

I'm new on visualforce and JSON, and I have a page that have many inputFields want to insert them by clicking on save, and get them back on click on edit button for example, I searched on google for examples but i found them not clear enough to understand, for me. I have an object name Book__c with Id,BookNum__c,BookTitle__c,Section__c (reference to sections object).

the input fields sorted in the VF page with repeat like this

```
<apex:pageBlock id="books">
     <apex:repeat value="{!counter}" var="count" rows="16">
         <apex:outputLabel value="{!count}" />
     </apex:repeat>
     <apex:repeat value="{!counter}" var="count" rows="16">
         <apex:inputField value="{!Book__c.BookTitle__c}" id="input"/>
     </apex:repeat>
     <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}" />
     <apex:commandButton value="Get to Edit" action="{!getBooksToEdit}" reRender="books" />
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Controller

```
public integer[] counter{set;get{
        return counter;
    }}
    public BooksController() {
            counter = new list<Integer>();
            for (integer i=101; i<=105; i++)
                counter.add(i);
    }
```

[image: Image1]

Comment: This is more easily accomplished without JSON. If you have a string reason to use JSON you should add that to the question but otherwise I suggest you remove JSON from your question.

Comment: instead of storing 10 records for a section (if i had many sections), I store it in a one record !

Answer (score 2):

Your posted code is missing the idea that to have many books displayed your controller will have to provide an array of books.

If you have a `Section__c` custom object that is a child of your `Book__c` custom object then a controller something like this:

```
public with sharing class BooksController {
    public Book__c[] books {
        get {
            if (books == null) {
                books = [
                        select Id, BookNum__c, BookTitle__c, (select Name from Sections__r)
                        from Book__c
                        order by BookNum__c
                        limit 10000
                        ];
            }
            return books;
        }
        private set;
    }
}
```

and a page something like this:

```
<apex:pageBlock id="books">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!books}" var="b">
        <apex:column value="{!b.BookNum__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Book Title">
             <apex:inputField value="{!b.BookTitle__c}" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Sections">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!b.Sections__r}" var="s">
                <apex:column value="{!s.Name}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

should give your roughly the output you want.

If instead of having a `Section__c` object you want to have say a `Sections__c` text field on `Book__c` that holds JSON, then you will have to do more work yourself. I would suggest adding jQuery to your page and when the page loads transforming the JSON into HTML inserted next to the other book information. But if you want editing too of the sections then you will have to add JavaScript code for new/update/delete of sections and that is more work still.